# My jQuery code stops working when I use & instead of $

Tags: jquery

I just started using jQuery and I love it. Don't know how I lived without it.

I started off small by doing some basic showing and hiding, and fading in, then fading back out. It works great.

My problem occurs when I decided to use the "&" symbol for my jQuery variables instead of the normal "$" (isn't that right?). I don't really like the look of the $ sign as it reminds my of my mortgage payment thats 3 months overdue. But I had to have this new MacBook Pro retina display...anyway I diverge.

So I'm trying to do basic stuff using the &, like so:

```
&('body').show('superfast');
```

But it's not working. I also tried to make all of the blink tags on my page blink twice as fast like this:

```
&('blink').animate({
    'speed': 'faster'
})
```

Lastly when the user puts their mouse over any of the images on my web page I want to play a cat sound...my website sells massage therapy sessions for dogs and the cat sound will probably make them happy right? I tried this:

```
&('image').mouseover(function(){
    var audio = new Audio("noise.mp3");
    audio.play();
});
```

Can somebody help me please? I really don't want to use the $ because it makes me realize all of the money I'm losing from my webpage until this code runs. Help?

Answer (score 5):

The reason `$` is used as a reference to the function `jQuery` is it's short, and also not a reserved symbol.

The `&` symbol would not work, as it's reserved for bitwise AND operations and thus cannot be used as a variable name.

Your choices are to use the `jQuery` function directly, such as:

```
jQuery(function () { ... });
```

Or use `$` such as:

```
$(function () { ... });
```

You could also assign something else, such as:

```
var _ = jQuery;
```

or

```
var IHateDollarSign = jQuery;
```

So long as the identifier is not reserved.

Answer (score 4):

You can use "jQuery" instead of "$"

```
$('body').show('superfast');
```

is the same as

```
jQuery('body').show('superfast');
```

Comment: good answer, but I think (hope) this question is a joke

Comment: Thanks Bruno seal. But I don't want to use the $ or jQuery. I really like the &. Can you help me figure out a way to use &?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that what you are trying to do is a good idea. You should not change that.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a random character. JQuery maps itself to $. you can map it by simply assigning the jQuery object to something like 'q' by writing this: `var q = window.jQuery;`

Comment: Uhh isn't `&` reserved in Javascript for a bitwise and?

Comment: Correct, thanks for the catch. code fixed.